# Excel VBA, set custom page size in Word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Having some difficulty... I have VBA code in Excel to open MS Word and change the page size to a custom size. I cannot get it to work, I've googled a few different ways to try it, I don't do this often and I think I'm missing something.

```
Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Dim objRange
Dim objSelection

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

objDoc.PageSetup.PageWidth = InchesToPoints(11.5)
objDoc.PageSetup.PageWidth = InchesToPoints(14.375)

<...rest of code>

objWord.Visible = True
```

At this point, I have tried "objDoc.PageSetup.PageWidth" as shown above, and I've also tried "objSelection.PageSetup.PageWidth" and "objWord.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.Pagewidth" - but it just keeps opening up an 8.5" x 11" letter paper document.

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Hi there, no error at all. It just opens with the letter page size.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Dim objRange
Dim objSelection

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

objDoc.PageSetup.PageWidth = objWord.InchesToPoints(11.5)
objDoc.PageSetup.PageWidth = objWord.InchesToPoints(14.375)



objWord.Visible = True
```

It still says letter, but the actual size is different -

[image]

Note your code has `pagewidth` twice, no height.

using -

```
objDoc.PageSetup.PageHeight = objWord.InchesToPoints(14.375)
```

[image]

Comment: Using `objDoc.PageSetup.PageWidth = objWord.InchesToPoints(11.5)` worked for me... thanks so much!

Comment: @LeahW if your question is solved, please be sure to click the green checkmark next to the answer that solved it. This will mark it as solved so others will know.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your custom page size like the following command;

```
objDoc.PageSetup.PaperSize = 9
```

If you want to set Word size with A4, you should set 9.
If you want to set Word size with A5, you should set 11.

Enumerations;

- 9=xlPaperA4
- 11=xlPaperA5

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
objDoc.PageSetup.PaperSize = xlPaperA4
```

The built-in paper sizes can be found here: [Excel Paper Sizes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlpapersize.aspx)

One of these might be close to your custom size.

Answer (score 0):

I use custom paper sizes.
Unfortunately Word appears to set all of these to papersize 41
However, at least in my case, when I set paperzize to 41
and then change the margins to a specific size, the papersize name is correct

This worked for me

```
    activedocument.PageSetup.PaperSize = 41
    activedocument.PageSetup.PageWidth = InchesToPoints(4.25)
    activedocument.PageSetup.Pageheight = InchesToPoints(5.5)
```